# Как изменить стиль checkbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox

Как можно создать такой чекбокс, который на фото?

[image]

Я плохо разбираюсь в создании стилей. :(

Comment: неплохо было бы понять: html или xaml

Comment: работа идёт в форме WPF, разумеется XAML)

Comment: @inkorpus1, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 6):

Как, как. Как обычно, стиль поменять. Отталкиваясь от этого: [*CheckBox Styles and Templates*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752319%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: По ссылке пишет _This topic is no longer available_

Comment: @MikhailDanshin: Хм, они опять поменяли структуру MSDN. Откатил на предыдущую серию. Спасибо за подсказку!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте этот код. По крайней мере для `IsEnabled = True` часть кода работает. Картинки подставьте свои.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" x:Key="CheckboxStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image x:Name="checkboxImage" Source="CheckBoxNormalDefault.png" Width="16"/>
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="checkboxImage" Property="Source" Value="CheckBoxNormalDefault.png"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="checkboxImage" Property="Source" Value="CheckBoxNormalChecked.png"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <!-- For disabled state. -->
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="checkboxImage" Property="Source" Value="CheckBoxDisabledDefault.png"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="checkboxImage" Property="Source" Value="CheckBoxDisabledChecked.png"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Инициализация стиля:

```
<CheckBox Style="{StaticResource CheckboxStyle}" />
```